# In Python post request json file 404

Tags: python, api

It occurred ERROR 404...
I can't understand what is wrong

json file

```json
{"place_name": "대저생태공원", "img_url": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcRRT1TkNZMCkAaZ-tlwXX_XL9UiaDkew5BDsnf4cMMt086OaBhAHlPWGisM-7GOFRwNaXKpGvxhTQZHfwNoyvKRXQ", "score": 4.2, "description": 1679, "address": "부산 강서구 대저1동 2314-11"}
```

python code

```py
import requests

# Api 호출
url = "https://f053a068dd0ea6.lhrtunnel.link/api/places"
response = requests.post(url= url, data='./j.json')
print(response)
```

api post code

```js
app.post('/api/add', (req, res) => {
  const {place_name, score, description, img_url, address} = req.body;
  connection.query(`INSERT INTO place VALUES (0, "${place_name}", ${score}, "${description}", "${img_url}", "${address}");`, (error, rows) => {
    if(error) console.log(error);
    res.send(rows);
  })
})
```

help me!

Comment: You're accessing api/places but the webserver implements api/add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong url.

You need to open the file and read the content otherwise you are sending ./j.json instead of the file content

```py
import requests

with open('./j.json') as f :
    data = f.read()
# Api 호출
url = "https://f053a068dd0ea6.lhrtunnel.link/api/add"
response = requests.post(url= url, data=data)
print(response)
```

Comment: While true, this would not cause a 404 error.

Comment: Didn't pay attention to that. Thanks

As @interjay said , the error 404 means not found. The error is coming from the wrong url your are using . URL should end with /api/add